# VS Code CLI List the Extensions installed for a given profile

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to sort out my 120 extensions in VSCode into profiles for each language so want to create a base to use for each, that will become the default after the surtout.

How do you use the cli to list each extension installed under a given profile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can use the `--profile` flag in conjunction with `--list-extensions`

i.e.

```
code --list-extensions --profile <MY PROFILE NAME>
```